# How to find maxima and local minima of this graph?

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

I know the global min for the graph is 5 at x. At 3 and 8, it would be local max. But here is the problem, the interval (0,8] doesn't include 0 so zero can't be the global max? If what I got so far is correct what is the global Max

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hufY8.png)

[image]

Comment: Not every function has a global max. Consider $f(x) = x$ on the open interval $(0, 1)$, or $g(x) = 1/x$ on the same interval.

Comment: Your function has no global maximum, but it has supremum...which is $\;6\;$ .

Comment: local max 3 ,8. local min 2. Global min at 5. Global max none is correct?